# How to remove all straight line shapes from a Microsoft Word document (*.docx)?

Tags: microsoft-word, regex, docx

I have a docx document that has many straight line shapes in different parts of the document. I am tasked to remove all of them. I could do it manually but the document is 160 pages long and each page has at least 3 straight line shapes in it, so **I was looking for a way to automatically delete all of them**.
Is there any way to do it either with regular expressions or with some other option in word?

Comment: .docx is just an XML file. Take a look at it in VSCode and see if the regex search tools can isolate the XML elements for them.

Comment: If you turn on Layout > Selection Pane, it shows a list of all the shape objects. If you just need them to disappear, you can "hide all" in one click. Otherwise, you still have to delete them one by one, but it's a bit faster from the list than by scrolling.

Answer (score 2):

This requires VBA code similar to the (untested) following code :

```
Public Sub DeleteLines()
    Dim shape As InlineShape
    For Each shape In ActiveDocument.InlineShapes
        If shape.Type = wdInlineShapeHorizontalLine Then
            shape.Delete
        End If
    Next shape
End Sub
```

This will delete all horizontal lines (`wdInlineShapeHorizontalLine`).
To delete other types of line-shapes, see
[WdInlineShapeType enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.wdinlineshapetype).

Comment: Well, when I navigate to "Layout > Selection Pane" as Cpt.Whale suggested, the lines I want to delete are marked as "Line X", where X is some number. I tried running your code but nothing got deleted...maybe because my lines are of some other type of object? I mean they are shapes, and they are also marked as Lines (Line X).

Comment: You could find out by modifying the above code. See [Determining Object Type (Visual Basic)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/early-late-binding/determining-object-type).

Comment: I added the following line to print all the object's Types inside the For loop:
```    
For Each shape In ActiveDocument.InlineShapes
        MsgBox shape.Type
```
I got only 2 Msgboxes to appear, that showed only the number '3' as the type object.
Either im missing something or there is something totally wrong with this document.

Comment: `3` stands for `wdInlineShapePicture`, meaning Picture. So the lines are not lines? Try to locate them using *Layout > Selection Pane* to find what they are. Keep a backup copy while manipulating the document.

Comment: visually they are lines. If I navigate to Layour > Selection Pane, they are marked as Lines as well (for example Line 204). Was the script you provided intended to remove lines? Because it did not work:/

Comment: Try replacing `ActiveDocument.InlineShapes` in the macro with `ActiveDocument.Shapes`.

Comment: I added your modification and now have:
```vba
Dim shape As Shape # changed it here cause of mismatch errors
    For Each shape In ActiveDocument.Shapes
```
but again it did not delete them. I tried using MsgBox again to print the shape.Type and got code 17 this time (it is referring to some other object in the document). If you'd like, we could discuss it further in chat or I could send you a small sample from this document to try it yourself and see if you can get to the bottom of this.

Comment: `17` is not an atomic value. it's perhaps `16+1`, meaning "wdInlineShapeWebVideo - A picture acting as a poster frame for a web video" and "wdInlineShapeEmbeddedOLEObject - Embedded OLE object". These are apparently not real lines. You could upload online a small sample from this document, and I'll have a look.